# trying to make a statement where if a number is too high it prints a certain word

Tags: python

Im trying to make an input so when you input a number I want it to print, for example blue if the number is over 20 but if its lower I want it to print red. Sorry if I sound dumb hahaha

Comment: Sounds great. Do you also have a question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd do that. Just change the values and operators per use

```
number = int(input("Enter Number: ")) 

if number > 20:
    print("Blue")
else:
    print("Red")
```

Comment: This won't actually work, because the result of `input()` is a string, which cannot be compared to a number.

Comment: I was focused on the logic but thank you. I have corrected my mistake it should work now